# My (LocalDB)\v11.0 is not "running"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, sql-server-express

In SqlServerManagementStudio (2012), (LocalDB)\v11.0 is not running in SSMS, I installed SqlExpress to use it from IIS.

[image]

What can I do to enable it?

Answer (score 4):

In my case - localdb did work for me, but one day it "Stopped" - I was not able to connect to it not from IDE, and not from code.

I killed its process **sqlservr.exe** I found in Task Manager (actually, all processes - it were 2 of them).

This fixed the issue for me - was able to connect and work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using (localdb)\v11.0, try to use (localdb)\mssqllocaldb as server name to connect to the LocalDB automatic instance.
This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this is as expected.

If you try to interact with your LocalDB server, everything should function as if it were started.

I found [a blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlexpress/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express) with an explanation:

> LocalDB doesn't create any database services; LocalDB processes are started and stopped automatically when needed. The application is just connecting to "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0" and LocalDB process is started as a child process of the application. A few minutes after the last connection to this process is closed the process shuts down.

Comment: But I'm not being able to work with it, I thought the it was the problem. I'm able to work with the other instance server (.\sqlexpress), but (localdb)\v11.0 doesn´t allow me to do anything, even if I log in my computer with the Administrator account, I get this error if I try to do something as restoring a database: "Property MasterDBPath is not available for Information 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Information'. This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights". I even removed it and reinstalled it using SqlLocalDB.msi

Comment: Haven't tried it, but a google search of your error came up with this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23609/sql-server-localdb-instance-error-restoring-backup-masterdbpath-not-available

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem several times. I always restart my pc and then it works.